# Trying to change all "p" tags to specified color stated in the code bellow

Tags: javascript, dom, userscripts

I'm getting a typeError because the script can't read property "style" of null.

I've tried to append the property to a variable, thinking it would work

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name New Script
// @namespace Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match https://simply-how.com/enhance-and-fine-tune-any-web-page-the-complete-user-scripts-guide
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript==
var pTag = document.getElementById("p");

pTag.style.color =  "#4040c9"

I expect for all the "p" tags to change to the color #4040c9
```

Comment: Why did you expect that to find all p elements?

Comment: You don't have an element with `id="p"` on the page. If you want all `<p>` tags, then you want to use `getElementsByTagName()`

Comment: document.get**Element**ById, singular, not plural.  If you want to change all the p tags to have a color, don't set an inline style on all of them.  Make a css rule.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getElementsByTagName` to store all `p` elements in an HTMLCollection object and then use a simple loop to change style for each element instance.

Example:

```
var pTag = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for(var i=0; i<pTag.length; i++)
  {
    pTag[i].style.color = "#4040c9";
  }
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` does not return an array but HTMLCollection.

Comment: Yes, you are correct :)